# Generating Settings Objects from Database via Factory Class

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, xml, factory-method

In an ASP.NET MVC application (C#) have a factory-like class that generates settings objects of `ISettingType` for my application.  However, some settings are very simple and a standard built-in such as a string or number type value can also suffice.  I think that the way that I'm doing this is very much a code smell though.

These settings are persisted within my database in a table that's acting as a key/value store.  The key is a `NVARCHAR(50)` column being the name of the setting also acting as the primary key, and the value field is an `XML` column.  Manipulating the XML directly is unnecessary, and I have various classes that implement the `ISettingType` interface, which includes methods for de/serialization from/to XML.  As I mentioned some of these settings are very simple and only require a single string or number value.

The factory looks like this:

```
public static class SettingsFactory
{
    private const string MODEL_NAMESPACE = "Company.Models.Administration.SettingTypes.";


    public static ISettingType Create(ApplicationSetting appSetting)
    {
        object setting = DeserializeValue(appSetting);
        var settingType = setting as ISettingType;
        if (settingType != null)
            return settingType;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Setting is not of a complex type requiring an ISettingType");
    }

    public static T Create<T>(ApplicationSetting appSetting)
    {
        if (typeof(ISettingType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            return (T)Create(appSetting);

        return (T) DeserializeValue(appSetting);
    }

    private static object DeserializeValue(ApplicationSetting appSetting)
    {
        XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(appSetting.SettingValue);
        if (rootElement.HasElements)
        {
            Type settingType = Type.GetType(MODEL_NAMESPACE + appSetting.SettingName);
            if (settingType != null)
            {
                using (XmlReader reader = rootElement.CreateReader())
                {
                    reader.MoveToContent();
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(settingType);
                    return (ISettingType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
        }

        var numeric = ConvertToNumber(rootElement.Value);
        return numeric ?? rootElement.Value;
    }

    private static object ConvertToNumber(string str)
    {
        decimal number;
        if (decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out number))
        {
            if (number % 1 == 0)
            {
                return (long)number;
            }

            return number;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

To clarify one thing the class `ApplicationSetting` is an EF entity storing the key/value pair within the database.

Having a factory that has two "get" (called `Create()` in the above code) methods where one only works for a specific type of setting seems like a code smell.  Additionally having a factory that creates both objects implementing the interface AND primitive types just feels "wrong," but I'm not really sure if wrapping these settings in tiny classes that have a single property so they can implement `ISettingType` is really the best way to handle this either.

The `ApplicationSetting` EF Entity class is just a simple POCO:

```
public class ApplicationSetting
{
     public string SettingName { get; set; }
     public string SettingValue { get; set; }
}
```

The `ISettingType` interface:

```
public interface ISettingType
{
    string SerializeValue();
    ApplicationSetting ToApplicationSetting();
}
```

I have an abstract base class that implements this:

```
public abstract class BaseSetting : ISettingType
{
    public virtual string SerializeValue()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Value");
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

            xmlWriter.Flush();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public virtual ApplicationSetting ToApplicationSetting()
    {
        var name = this.GetType().Name;
        var value = this.SerializeValue();

        return new ApplicationSetting
        {
            SettingName = name,
            SettingValue = value
        };
    }
}
```

An example of a class derived from this is `Smtp`:

```
public class Smtp : BaseSetting
{
    public class SmtpServer
    {
        [XmlText]
        [Url]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Host")]
        public string Host { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("port")]
        [Display(Name = "Port")]
        public int Port { get; set; }

        public SmtpServer()
        {
            Port = 25;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("Server")]
    public SmtpServer Server { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Username")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Password")]
    public string SerializedPassword
    {
        get { return Password.EncryptString(); }
        set { this.Password = value.DecryptString(); }
    }
}
```

`Smtp` is a view model and is used as below from controller methods:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSmtpForm()
{
   //db is my Entity Framework context
    var setting = await db.ApplicationSettings.SingleAsync(s => s.SettingName.Equals("Smtp"));
    var smtp = SettingFactory.Create<Smtp>(setting);
    return PartialView("SmtpForm", smtp);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateSmtp(Smtp smtp)
{
    //perform validation -- below is if passed
    var setting = smtp.ToApplicationSetting();
    db.ApplicationSettings.Attach(setting);
    db.Entity(setting).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    //Send data back to client
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! I hope you get great reviews! =)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose xml and not json? With the latest libraries it's a piece of cake to (de)serialize such settings without doing anything on your own.

Comment: @t3chb0t Only because MS SQL Server natively supports XML with the XML column type. Using the built-in libraries in the System.Xml namespace (and sub-namespaces) makes it fairly simple (although it does require a lot of boilerplate).  What libraries are you referring to so I can take a look for a future project/refactoring?

Comment: Let's take the most popular one: [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). I use mostly either with json files or storing settings in database tables.

Comment: @t3chb0t Oh I see what you're saying.  I use JSON.NET all the time, I thought you were referring to something specially designed for creating & storing settings.  I'm assuming you just use a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column with them?  Literally, the only reason I went down the XML route was due to the built-in support on the database server to make it easy for migrations in the future if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *However, some settings are very simple and a standard built-in such as a string or number type value can also suffice.*

I think your entire code would be much simpler (and efficient) if *all* settings implemented the `ISettingType` interface, *regardless* of whether that's a "complex type" or a "simple" value.

Just from the caller's perspective - by treating "mere simple strings" and "puny little integer values" differently, you've added the burden of knowledge to the caller's side:

```
var setting = _factory.Create(settingEntity); // hmmm wait a minute...
```

Whether that call will succeed or fail can't be determined at compile-time, because it depends entirely on some serialized value stored in `settingEntity`. It's putting the caller in a very uncomfortable position:

```
var setting = _factory.Create<int>(settingEntity); // or is it <bool>? <string>? <DateTime>?
```

If I'm new to the code base, I've no idea. Either I go by trial-and-error, or I inspect the serialized data in `settingEntity` *at run-time* to see which overload will work.

All that, just because someone decided an `int` setting was "too simple" to warrant being properly serialized and exposed to the API as an `ISettingType`.

If every single setting implemented the same interface regardless of its type, this calling code will work every time:

```
var setting = _factory.Create(settingEntity);
```

"Oh my God, but you're so careless about object allocations!" - Yeah, well, until that's measured and proven to be a bottleneck somewhere, then it's not a problem. I'd deem this "special-casing" of standard built-in types, nothing less than *premature optimization* - that's right, *the root of all evil*.

---

But let's look at the implementation, regardless.

> ```
> public static ISettingType Create(ApplicationSetting appSetting)
> {
>     object setting = DeserializeValue(appSetting);
>     var settingType = setting as ISettingType;
>     if (settingType != null)
>         return settingType;
>
>     throw new InvalidOperationException("Setting is not of a complex type requiring an ISettingType");
> }
> ```

IMO every scope should have its braces, so that `if` scope needs braces - yes, even for one single-line `return` statement.

Why is `settting` explicitly declared as `object` when `var` is sporadically used elsewhere? I'm not sure I'd be able to grasp when to and when *not* to use `var` in that code base. Besides, it could be simplified to this:

```
var result = DeserializeValue(appSetting) as ISettingType;
if (result == null) { throw new InvalidOperationException(...); }
return result;
```

Actually, that exception should *probably* be a more specific `ArgumentException`. After all, an `InvalidOperationException` is normally thrown *when the state of the object doesn't allow that operation* - and we're dealing with a `static` method, on a `static` class: having *state* in this context would be very questionable.. and the problem stems from the supplied argument anyway - I'd definitely go with an `ArgumentException` here.

In the circumstances, I like that you're throwing an exception here, instead of just returning `null`: it makes that much less for the caller to care about already.

---

This is worrying:

> ```
> Type settingType = Type.GetType(MODEL_NAMESPACE + appSetting.SettingName);
> ```

That means the settings namespace is carved in stone, cast in concrete, completely unrefactorable (that needs to be a word). If some smartypants newcomer comes in and moves all settings to `Company.Models.Settings`, and doesn't update the `MODEL_NAMESPACE` constant, everything falls apart. Why is that constant declared so far from where it's used anyway? Clearly it belongs in the `DeserializeValue` scope.

I don't like that there's a magic string in the data that needs to match not only the type, but also the namespace of that type. I think I'd prefer switching over an `enum` and store an `int` value instead; there would be some static dictionary mapping enum values to setting types, with a comment explaining why each enum has an explicit value:

```
// these values are stored in the db; DO NOT CHANGE THEM!
private static readonly IDictionary<SettingType, Type> SettingTypeMap =
    new Dictionary<SettingType, Type> {
        { SettingType.Foo, typeof(FooSetting) },
        { SettingType.Bar, typeof(BarSetting) },
        //{ SettingType.Smurf, typeof(SmurfSetting) },
    };
```

And that eliminates the frail `Type.GetType` code, and now if a happy coder walks in and moves all settings elsewhere, or renames them, nothing breaks.

---

I have a hard time seeing why this one needs to return an `object`:

> ```
> private static object ConvertToNumber(string str)
> {
>     decimal number;
>     if (decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out number))
>     {
>         if (number % 1 == 0)
>         {
>             return (long)number;
>         }
>
>         return number;
>     }
>
>     return null;
> }
> ```

It returns either a `decimal`, a `long` (`Int64`? Really?), or a `null` reference, and incurs a boxing penalty on the way out, which nullifies the type safety of generics when you un-box it here:

> ```
> return (T) DeserializeValue(appSetting);
> ```

Not to mention, that's presumably casting the `long` back into an `int` most of the time. Why not give it the `T` and make it generic?

```
private static Nullable<T> ConvertToNumber<T>(string str)
{
    decimal number;
    if (decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Any, ...)
    {
        return new Nullable<T>(number);
    }
    return null;
}
```

That way you're not boxing the value type into an object, and you're only casting to the type the caller asked for - i.e. if an `int` is needed, then you're not returning a `long`.

But then again, half of that is moot if every setting implements the `ISettingType` interface.

Comment: Thanks so much for the review!  I knew this class needed a rewrite desperately, but just needed another brain on it.  Definitely going with the every setting implements `ISettingType` path.